# Installing python packages in the correct version

Tags: raspbian, python

I've built python 3.4 from source and installed it. I also installed pip. When I try to install packages with 'pip3 install', it installs to python 3.2. How can I make pip install packages for python 3.4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't the correct command

python3.4 -m pip install SomePackage

See https://docs.python.org/3.4/installing/index.html